# IE ignoring CSS even though it has higher specificity

Tags: css, css-specificity

I have some sliding door button css.. I use a button tag and two inner spans.

I have this to specify the background image of a normal button;

```
button span {
 background: url(button_right.png) no-repeat top right;
}
```

Which is the default button colour. I then have a 'gray' button (i give the button a class of 'gray').

```
button.gray span {
 background: url(button_right_gray.png) no-repeat top right;
}
```

For some reason .. IE(8) doesn't like this and ignores the gray css keeping the original image as the background. However, the following "hover" css DOES work in IE;

```
button.gray:hover span span {
      color: #6c6c6c;
      background-position: left -29px;
  }
```

I thought that 'button.gray span' has higher specificity than just 'button span' (it does in all other browsers).

EDIT:
Ok, so I've discovered the problem. In my CSS declaration I had the following

```
button.gray span,
  button:disabled span {
background: url(button_right.png) no-repeat top right;
}
```

If I remove the button:disabled span from the declaration list, it works!

Comment: Why does the third code block have two spans? For the second code block did you try button.gray span span?

Comment: Because the html is like so;

<button><span><span>Button Text</span></span></button>

The first span is the right "cap" of the button, the second one is the left area which contains the text.

Comment: I just mocked up a test page using the HTML and CSS exactly as you've described here and it works fine for me in IE8. Is there something else in your CSS that could be influencing things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE [does not support the `:disabled` pseudo class selector](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-disabled). IE's behaviour is to skip the entire rule when it encounters an invalid or unrecognised selector (which is actually [in line with the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#rule-sets) - even if not supporting `:disabled` in the first place is not!), so that would explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Undestandable, but would have been nice if IE had warned me ;)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding !important to it? i.e.

```
    button.gray span {
      background: url(button_right_gray.png) no-repeat top right !important;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried !importants too but to no avail. In the IE developer tools (I know they're a piece of s***) the .gray stuff doesn't appear AT ALL in the right CSS panel.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at the image itself? Using colours instead of images, ie8 seems to display the .gray class fine:

http://screencast.com/t/YzA4MGEx

Answer (score 0):

As per my edit;

Ok, so I've discovered the problem. In my CSS declaration I had the following

button.gray span,
  button:disabled span {
background: url(button_right.png) no-repeat top right;
}

If I remove the button:disabled span from the declaration list, it works! What is IE's issue with button:disabled as it completely stops listening to the entire declaration?